# running a dart project on an android tablet with termux

Tags: android, unit-testing, dart, termux

i have to make a roundtrip, some hours in the train, and thought i could do some work, on an android tablet....
i have  termux installed, there i installed dart, git-cloned my (working) repo, but the tests fail with :

```
~/projects/dart_fibu$ dart test test/settings_test.dart
00:02 +0: loading test/settings_test.dart   
Could not find a command named 
"/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/dart-sdk/bin/snapshots/frontend_server.dart.snapshot".
```

program itself runs fine, but since i use the tests to dev the thing...

wondering what's going wrong there, and how to fix this?
the project was started as command line project and then imported into android studio, it runs fine on my main dev machine and on a raspberry pi...

i googled, but didn't find anything relevant

but... in the termux install there seems to be more stuff missing:
when i run vim (with the dart plugins activated) i get also a missing analysis_server.dart.snapshot error....